# TestCase in laravel package not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, testcase

I'm converting my open source app as a package and it always throws error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Laracommerce\Tests\TestCase' not found in .... on line 18
```

[image]

Based on other comments on every search I made, I just need to define it in my package composer.json's `autoload-dev` the location of my tests but still getting the error.

Comment: If composer install doesn't work, you can also try composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `Laracommerce\Tests` namespace but into the composer file you declared `Laracommerce\Core\Tests`
you need to:
a. change classes namespaces `Laracommerce\Core\...` to `Laracommerce\...`
b. or simply modify your composer file like this

```
"autoload":{
  "psr-4": {
    "Laracommerce\\": "src/"
  }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Laracommerce\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

Then you need to run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: you're welcome. It sounds interesting the package you're making. If is open source, and do you want maybe I can see that package and help you if I have some free time

Answer (score 0):

Try running a `composer install`, sometimes I get the same error but it gets fixed after that.